# How to perform a SwiftUI animation when an @Observable property changes

Tags: animation, swiftui, observable

I'm animating a square into a circle in the following snippet. My view observes the `isCircle` property to determine whether to draw a circle or square. The `MyData#doSomethingExpensive` method is meant to simulate a long running task which, upon finishing, triggers the UI to animate (in this case animating a square to a circle).

This actually works as intended, but I have a `withAnimation` call in my `@Observable` UI model. I would rather have `withAnimation` inside the view, if possible. I would also like to continue using the `@Observable` API instead of switching back to `ObservableObject` conformance. Is there a way to refactor this such that the view will respond to changes in `isCircle` with the same animation that I have here:

```swift
import SwiftUI

@Observable
final class MyData {
    var isCircle = false
    func doSomethingExpensive() {
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(Int.random(in: 300...800)))
            withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 1.5)) {
                self.isCircle.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let myData = MyData()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if myData.isCircle {
                Circle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 200)
            } else {
                Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button("Animate later") {
                myData.doSomethingExpensive()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a reasonable approach that works for my case. It requires wrapping the `if` in a ZStack and applying the `.animation(value:)` modifier to that ZStack:

```swift
@Observable
final class MyData {
    var isCircle = false
    func doSomethingExpensive() {
        Task {
            try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(Int.random(in: 300...800)))
            self.isCircle.toggle()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let myData = MyData()
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ZStack {
                if myData.isCircle {
                    Circle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 200)
                } else {
                    Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
                }
            }.animation(.smooth(duration: 1.5), value: myData.isCircle)

            Button("Animate later") {
                myData.doSomethingExpensive()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is, you could move the `Task{...}` to the view, such as:

```
@Observable
final class MyData {
    var isCircle = false
    
    func doSomethingExpensive() async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(Int.random(in: 300...800))) // <--- here
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   let myData = MyData()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if myData.isCircle {
                Circle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 200)
            } else {
                Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button("Animate later") {
                Task { // <--- here
                    try await myData.doSomethingExpensive()
                    withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 1.5)) {
                        myData.isCircle.toggle()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT-1:

Another approach to react to the completion of the long running task (doSomethingExpensive),
is to use a second `var isDone` and listen to that change (using `.onChange`) to trigger the animation.

For example:

```
@Observable
final class MyData {
    var isCircle = false
    var isDone = false // <--- here

    func doSomethingExpensive() async throws {
        try await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(Int.random(in: 300...800)))
        isDone.toggle() // <--- here
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    let myData = MyData()

    // alternative
    // @State private var isCircle = false // and adjust the code
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if myData.isCircle {
                Circle().fill(.blue).frame(width: 200)
            } else {
                Rectangle().fill(.red).frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            Button("Animate later") {
                Task {
                    try await myData.doSomethingExpensive()
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: myData.isDone) {  // <--- here
                withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 1.5)) {
                    myData.isCircle.toggle()  // <--- here
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That works too. I was hoping for a way to react to the change of the observed `isCircle` property with an animation. All the button would do is call `myData.doSomethingExpensive`, and elsewhere in the definition of the `body` I would react to the change of `isCircle`. Perhaps an API around those needs is not built yet. I will keep the question open for some more ideas. Thanks!

Comment: updated my answer with a different approach to trigger the animation when the long running task is done.

Comment: Oh yeah that's a good idea too. It adds a bit more state but the logic is nice and clear. I found another alternative too that I posted below. It doesn't rely on any additional state. The downside is I don't find the declarative animation API particularly obvious.

Answer (score 1):

FYI `let myData = MyData()` is a memory leak in SwiftUI because `View` structs have no lifetime so that object will be init over and over again never freed.

If you use the new `.task` modifier you don't need an object at all to manage the lifetime of the async work, that's all handled automatically leaving you free to focus on your own code. e.g. something like:

```
@State var started = false 
@State var isCircle = false

var body: Some View {

    /// Circle code

    Button(started ? "Stop" : "Start") {
        started.toggle()
    }
    .task(id: started) { // runs on appear and when id changes, cancelled on disappear and on id change
        if started == false { return }
        let result = await doSomethingExpensive()
        withAnimation(.smooth(duration: 1.5)) {
             isCircle.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Example CounterView I mentioned in comments:

```
struct CounterView: View {
    @State var counter = 0
    
    var body: View {
         VStack {
             Button("Increment \(counter)") {
                 counter += 1
             }
             ContentView()
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but your first bit is incorrect. If you put a `deinit` in MyData with a log statement and run the example you will see the myData instance is not freed. As ContentView is mutated, a reference to the underlying reference type is passed around, not instantiated anew. For the second part: my example is distilled out from a larger project that is driven by an Obervable, so adding state to the view is not a good option for me.

Comment: "As ContentView is mutated" - Views are immutable. The memory leak will be visible when `ContentView` is re-init by parent `body`, e.g. App's `body`. The object will be init over and over again, hence a memory leak. I don't know if it will ever be freed.

Comment: Ah, your edit makes sense to me now. When it said "immediately lost" I thought you meant freed

Comment: "The memory leak will be visible when ContentView is re-init by parent body, e.g. App's body. The object will be init over and over again, hence a memory leak". How can I force this to happen? I am animating the view in and out and only ever see `MyData#init` get called a single time. I do see `ContentView#body` accessed on each animation, which returns a new view body, but I never see `ContentView` or `MyData` initialized more than once

Comment: App's `body` could be re-computed at any time while the app is running but if you want to simulate `body` being recomputed you can wrap ContentView in a CounterView with a button that increments a state counter and the button text shows the number.

Comment: I added code to the answer to demonstrate that

Comment: It was an interesting exercise. I am convinced that there is no leak. Here is a repro and you can see that forcing ContentView to init does in fact free the dependency on the Observable object: https://gist.github.com/lzell/6402da9692073934fc4f243291183ac2  WDYT?

Comment: It's outputing "In initializer of DoesThisLeak" every time. In terms of SwiftUI that is a bad leak to init a heap object inside `body` computation which is designed to only be for value types. Also, any internal state of the object is lost. I understand its a bit different from a leak where the memory is occupied forever but in SwiftUI we do call this a leak too.

Comment: That makes sense to me. We were working with different definitions of leak. That was fun though! It's good to poke around with these fundamental concepts